# IQKeyboardManager hides keyboard when tapped on UITextField

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextfield, resignfirstresponder, iqkeyboardmanager

I have two text fields. I am using this code in `textFieldDidBeginEditing`, but it's not dismissing the keyboard.

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if(textField==textFieldOne)
    {

    }

    else if (textField==textFieldTwo)
    {
        [[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager]resignFirstResponder]
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you get the solution?

Answer (score 2):

This might help Try

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
if(textField==textFieldOne)
{

}

else if (textField==textFieldTwo)
{
[self.view endEditing:YES];
}
}
```

Comment: shouldResignOnTouchOutside use this property of IQKeyboardManager to hide keyboard

Comment: It hides keyboard only if we tap outside, on when tapped inside the second text field.